# Call to $.ajax is changing my window scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scroll

I'm running into a really weird bug... As soon as my JS code enters into my `success` function off of a jQuery `$.ajax` call, the scroll postition on my window jumps down to the bottom of the page. This is a real problem for me since I'm working on a mobile page loading, and don't want this jarring animation.

I tracked it down by literring my code with `console.debug($(window).scrollTop());` calls, and it consitently changes from `0` (what it should be) to some number in the hundreds (bad) right after entering in the success callback, before any of the callback code is executed.

I'm having the same problem in Safari and Chrome, both with User-Agent set to iOS 5.

---

Here's a snippet of the problem area:

```
  console.debug($(window).scrollTop()); //= 0
  // store the user's direction
  M.advance = args.advance;

  console.debug($(window).scrollTop()); //= 0
  // setup the existing page for a load event
  M.init_change();

  console.debug($(window).scrollTop()); //= 0
  $.ajax({
    url: args.url,
    success: function(resp) {
      console.debug($(window).scrollTop()); //= 616
      var $resp = $(resp);

      console.debug($(window).scrollTop()); //= 616
      // cycle through and get the elements we want
      for(var i = 0, l = $resp.length; i < l; i++) {
        var $node = $($resp[i]);
        if($node.is('nav[data-role="top-nav"]]')) M.current.nav = $node;

        // ...
```

Anyone have any idea what's going on here? I'm at my wits-end...

---

See the full file here: https://gist.github.com/1499965

Comment: Can we see a complete working example? Is there any other code that might execute after the `$.ajax` call but before the callback?

Comment: What triggers the ajax request in the first place? Can you show how the above code is called?

Comment: Added the whole file as a gist to the question above. I'm getting this when clicking my browser's back button (so it's getting called with [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js)).

Comment: I would say that the problem is *after* `.ajax()` call. Before AJAX `scrollTop` is 0 and in success method which occurs after some time `scrollTop` is 616. It has nothing to do with AJAX itself, it just means that the problem occurs between AJAX request and AJAX response.

Comment: @neezer wait a minute... this fires when you go back via the browser? Wouldn't it go to the scroll position where you were last in that page?

Comment: is the push state using the window hash which is adjusting the page location?

Comment: @Patches When the back event happens, it's doing a fresh page load (see the full script above), and pushing a new state rather than returning to the previous one, so I wouldn't think it's caching the previous scroll position... is there anyone I can confirm this that you know of? Or better yet, disable it? I don't mind if the new page loads the previous scroll position (actually, I'd prefer it), my issue is that it loads the scroll position on the current page rather than the page you're going "back" to.

Comment: @neezer you're freshly loading data into the page, but the page from the browser's point of view is not being refreshed. By definition, an ajax data retrieval/dom manipulation happens outside of the page's life cycle. So, this may be a clue to what's going on. Since you're apparently creating UI on the fly out of the ajax result, it doesn't have an existing place to go to until you make it with the ajax results - resulting in it being at the top till it's got a 616 position to go to while the ajax is doing it's thing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I was correct in my comments as to what's going on:

In your $.ajax success function, when you know you're rebuilding the page and want the scroll position set to the top, do:

```
$("html").scrollTop(0);
```

Come to think on it, that might fix it even if I was wrong.

**Update:**
You could put it in $.ajax's 'complete' event, which fires after the success and error events in the ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
        url: args.url,
        success: function(resp) {
          // your success code
        },
        error: function() { console.error('something went wrong'); },
        complete: function() {
             window.scrollTo(0,0); // or the $('html').scrollTop(0); from before
      });
```

**Testing idea:** By default $.ajax fires asynchronously, so other things are executing while it's making the call. Just to rule out the possibility that something else that comes afterwards is resetting the scroll position, you could put `async: false,` in your $.ajax code.

Comment: I've already tried this with `$(window).scrollTop(0);` with no success: same behavior. `$('html').scrollTop(0);` doesn't make a difference either. Any other suggestions?

Comment: you could try the straight up javascript: window.scrollTo(0,0); Note it's 'To' not 'Top'. It probably wouldn't work, though: the other not working probably means whatever's happening is happening after that point. You could try putting it in a complete event on that $.ajax. That would ensure it happens after everything else in that ajax call. I'll update my answer with that.